# jQuery append element with object values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I want to append a `<ul>` element depending on the values contained in the object `option`. I am looking to add in `<li>` elements under the top level `<ul>` and then if the object has another value contained under then add a child `<ul>` which contains further `<li>` elements and so on...

I have sorted out the first level to create an `<li>` for each first level option and however adding another `.each()` function creates a random `[object Object]` before and the sub options don't order as desired.

An suggestions how I can make this work as desired my example code is below.

```
<ul id="menu">
</ul>

<script>
var option = {
    'option 1' : {
        'option 1 sub option 1' : {},
        'option 1 sub option 2' : {},
        'option 1 sub option 3' : {}

    },
    'option 2' : {
        'option 2 sub option 1' : {},
        'option 2 sub option 2' : {}
    },

    'option 3' : {
        'option 3 sub option 1' : {},
        'option 3 sub option 2' : {}
    }
}

var menu = $('#menu'); // target menu container

$.each(option, function(key, value) {

$(menu).append('<li data-option="' + key + '">' + key +
(value === 'undefined' ? '' : '<ul class="menu2">'
+

// Add more <li> elements for each sub option contained under each option
$.each(value, function(key, value) {
    $('.menu2').append(key);
})

+ '</ul>') + 
'</li>');

});

</script>
```

Comment: where is your if/else condition...if you are checking values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have 2 levels, Carsten's answer will work perfectly.
Incase theres an arbitrary depth, you will need a recursive solution.

```js
var option = {
    'option 1' : {
        'option 1 sub option 1' : {},
        'option 1 sub option 2' : {},
        'option 1 sub option 3' : {}

    },
    'option 2' : {
        'option 2 sub option 1' : {},
        'option 2 sub option 2' : {}
    },

    'option 3' : {
        'option 3 sub option 1' : {},
        'option 3 sub option 2' : {}
    }
}

function buildList(ul,data){
 for(var key in data){
  var li = $('<li>'+key+'</li>')
  if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data[key])){ // checks if there is another <ul> necesarry
   var sub_ul = $('<ul></ul>')
   buildList(sub_ul,data[key]) // do the same for the sub-ul
   li.append(sub_ul)
  }
  ul.append(li)
 }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  buildList($('#list'),option)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="list"></ul>
```

You can use it by calling `buildList()` and passing the target `ul` element in which the list should be put, and the data.

Comment: This helps a lot with a few tweaks this should work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit unclear to me what it is you want 100%, but try the following

```
var menu = $('#menu'); // target menu container
$.each(option, function(key, value) {
  var elem = "<li>" + key + "<ul>";
  $.each(value, function(i, x) {
    elem += "<li>" + i + "</li>"
  })
  elem += "</ul></li>"
  menu.append(elem);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var option = {
  'option 1': {
    'option 1 sub option 1': {},
    'option 1 sub option 2': {},
    'option 1 sub option 3': {}

  },
  'option 2': {
    'option 2 sub option 1': {},
    'option 2 sub option 2': {}
  },

  'option 3': {
    'option 3 sub option 1': {},
    'option 3 sub option 2': {}
  }
}

var menu = $('#menu'); // target menu container
$.each(option, function(key, value) {
  var elem = "<li>" + key + "<ul>";
  $.each(value, function(i, x) {
    elem += "<li>" + i + "</li>"
  })
  elem += "</ul></li>"
  menu.append(elem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```